# how can I skip a specific number of lines of a script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, termux

I have created a bash script named call.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
termux-tts-speak whom doyou want to call
var="$(termux-speech-to-text)"
if [ "$var" = "Pappu" ]
then
termux-tts-speak calling to pappu
termux-telephony-call xxxxxxxxxx

elif [ "$var" = "call me" ]
then
 termux-tts-speak calling to you
termux-telephony-call xxxxxxxxxx

else
termux-tts-speak sorry I can not understand say it again
fi
```

I runs the script using the command

```
$bash call.sh
```

But if I want to execute the script skipping first 3 line without modify the bash file.
How can I do that help me please?

Comment: If you skip the first 3 lines, you won't set `$var`.

Comment: You could try: `sed 1,3d call.sh | bash`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `tail` command and pipe it to `bash`:

```
tail -n +4 call.sh | bash
```

But a better idea would be to use command-line arguments and test in the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" != "--noask" ]
then
    termux-tts-speak whom do you want to call
fi

var="$(termux-speech-to-text)"
if [ "$var" = "Pappu" ]
then
    termux-tts-speak calling to pappu
    termux-telephony-call xxxxxxxxxx
elif [ "$var" = "call me" ]
then
    termux-tts-speak calling to you
    termux-telephony-call xxxxxxxxxx
else
    termux-tts-speak sorry I cannot understand say it again
fi
```

Then you can run the script like this to skip the first command:

```
./call.sh --noask
```